# Saved for web in Photoshop sliced page looks bad in IE

Tags: html, css

I made web page via Photoshop, sliced it and saved for web and uploaded the html file. It looks just fine in Firefox and Chrome, but IE it is whole different story. Any one know how to fix it and why I`m getting this black padding?

```
IE:
```

[image: IE]

```
Firefox, Chrome & Safari:
```

[image: Firefox]

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Shamir Applications</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (Webpage08.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="960" height="720" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="11">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_01.png" width="960" height="237" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="6">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_02.png" width="130" height="483" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Webpage08_03.png" width="138" height="36" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="6">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_04.png" width="142" height="483" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_05.png" width="138" height="36" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="6">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_06.png" width="140" height="483" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_07.png" width="138" height="36" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="6">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_08.png" width="134" height="483" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="5">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_09.png" width="138" height="447" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_10.png" width="138" height="13" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_11.png" width="138" height="13" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_12.png" width="14" height="146" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Webpage08_13.png" width="110" height="110" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_14.png" width="14" height="146" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_15.png" width="16" height="434" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Webpage08_16.png" width="110" height="110" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="4">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_17.png" width="12" height="434" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/Webpage08_18.png" width="110" height="36" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_19.png" width="110" height="324" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_20.png" width="138" height="17" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Webpage08_21.png" width="138" height="271" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE9, but it looks the same in all IEs, 9,8,7

Comment: can you post your html code? or better a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try switching from using the tables mode to using the css export instead?

With regard to Matei Mihai's answer you should probably add this as well:

```
img {
   border:0;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   display:block; /* This often removes extra spacing around images in IE */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to put this in your css file

```
img {
   border:0;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
}
```

or in the head tag write

```
<style type="text/css">
    img {
       border:0;
       padding:0;
       margin:0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Tried: tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

img {
       border:0;
       padding:0;
       margin:0;
    }    ----And didn`t helped